# AOSP build hangs at the beginning of build

Tags: android-source

I am developing a system with the AOSP fork, rowboat. It was working until today, now I get this:

```
$ time make -j8 TARGET_PRODUCT=beagleboneblack OMAPES=4.x droid showcommands
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.2.2
TARGET_PRODUCT=beagleboneblack
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.13.0-29-generic-x86_64-with-LinuxMint-17-qiana
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=JDQ39
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/tools/findleaves.py", line 98, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "build/tools/findleaves.py", line 92, in main
    results = list(set(perform_find(mindepth, prune, dirlist, filename)))
  File "build/tools/findleaves.py", line 31, in perform_find

real    7m19.311s
user    0m0.236s
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir, followlinks=True):
sys 0m0.104s
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk

atilla@atilla-vaiod$     for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
```

snip(this goes on so many lines).

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 294, in walk
    for x in walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 284, in walk
    if isdir(join(top, name)):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 41, in isdir
    st = os.stat(s)
KeyboardInterrupt
^C
```

Comment: I added some print statements to build/tools/findleaves.py, did not get any output. However, if I let it run for half an hour, it eventually terminates with a segfault. I suspect it got caught in a recursive loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. For some reason, the output is suppressed when the script is called from makefile. I ran the script manually, and found some recursive symlinks. Removed them and it is working again.

EDIT: Here is how I diagnosed the problem.

The build starts from build/core/main.mk, which invokes build/tools/findleaves.py. This script searches the entire source tree for files called `Android.mk` and stitches them together to create a temporary, gargantuan makefile.

If you start a build and cancel it by pressing Ctrl-C in the first few seconds, you will see the familiar keyboard interrupt message from Python. When I did it, the Python stack dump was several pages tall, as the script searches the directory tree recursively.

What I did was:

1. I added a simple print statement into the script to see what directory it scans.
2. This is important: I invoked the script directly, instead of through the makefile. This way, I can see its output, which would otherwise consumed by the makefile. Printing the traces to stderr instead of stdout will probably work as well.

The problem was, I created some extra subdirectories in the kernel directory to "install" modules and firmware, to make it easy for me to copy later. The `make modules-install` command installs a symlink back to the kernel source tree, pointing where the modules come from. So the there is a file `kernel/deploy/lib/modules/3.8.13/source` which is a symlink back to the `kernel/` directory.

The Python script follows symlinks and tries to scan a tree with infinite depth.

Comment: Could you please provide more information on how you found the recursive loop and where the recursive symlinks resided?

Answer (score -1):

Switch to python2.7 and try           `

Comment: The traceback clearly shows the OP is **already** using Python 2.7. Why did you feel this would help here?